# I get the Path error while running Kaggle?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

```
from fastai.vision import *

path = Path('Path_to_the_X-ray_image_folders') 

np.random.seed(41)
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train="Train", valid ="Valid",
    ds_tfms=get_transforms())

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I could not understand the source of the error. Can you heenter code herelp me ? Thank you.

Comment: can you try printing the path as print(path) to make sure files exist in path

Answer (score 0):

instead of running it with local path can you try the code with MNIST files. 
from the library examples get_transforms function should be called before from_folder called.

https://docs.fast.ai/vision.data.html

```
path = untar_data(URLs.MNIST_SAMPLE); path
tfms = get_transforms(do_flip=False)
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, ds_tfms=tfms, size=24)
```